# How do I add 3 bytes and return an integer number?

Tags: c#, int, byte, int32

Lets assume that I have a hex string of

> 00 00 04 01 11 00 08 00 06 C2 C1 BC

With this the 7th, 8th, and 9th octet are a number I need to generate. The hex is

> 00 06 C2

This number turns out to be `1730`. With the following, how can I simplify this?

```
byte b1 = 0x00;
byte b2 = 0x06;
byte b3 = 0xC2;

Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToString(b1, 16)) + (Convert.ToString(b2, 16)) + (Convert.ToString(b3, 16)), 16));
```

I know there has to be a simpler way. I tried `Console.WriteLine((b1 + b2 + b3).ToString());` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
int result = b3 | (b2 << 8) | (b1 << 16);
```

Assuming that b1, b2 and b3 are the `byte` values that you need to convert.

The [`<<` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1sway8w%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) shifts its operand left by the specified number of bits.

Comment: This worked perfectly! I will mark this as the answer as soon as it lets me!

Comment: As a small note: when dealing with `byte` arithmetic, `|` would be preferable to `+`; this may be important when "negative" numbers are involved (where the MSB is set)

Comment: (the OP put the `+` => `|` through as a suggested edit... feel free to change it back, but I maintain `|` improves the answer)

Comment: I was just changing the + to a | but it required me to change 6 characters to make an edit so I added a comment at the end.

Comment: @MarcGravell True dat - I wasn't too concerned since it was only 3 bytes (and so `+` would always work), but it's best to do it the right way.

Comment: @MarcGravell Actually in this case it is always safe to use `+` because the bits in the bytes don't overlap - but it's better to use `|` because that will always work even in cases when the bits do overlap. Best practice and all that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `BitConverter` class to convert an array of bytes to an int.

```
// Add the bytes to an array, starting with b3, then b2, b1 and 0 to
// make it 4 bytes in total.
byte[] b = new byte[] { 0xC2, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00 };
int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(b, 0);
```

`i` will now have the value `1730`.

Comment: That's a pretty hard way of doing something fairly simple, though - and it opens all sorts of questions about "endianness" etc. I'll work, but to be done properly you'd need to check `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`, etc

Comment: Yes, I realize that, but didn't want to make it more complicated than it already was. I prefer the bitshifting way, but wanted to propose an alternative to the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
    byte b1 = (byte)0x00;
    byte b2 = (byte)0x06;
    byte b3 = (byte)0xC2;
    int i = ((b1 & 0xFF) << 16) | ((b2 & 0xFF) << 8) | (b3 & 0xFF);
```

**EDIT:**

```
    byte b1 = (byte)0x00;
    byte b2 = (byte)0x06;
    byte b3 = (byte)0xC2;
    int i = (b1 << 16) | (b2 << 8) | b3;
```

Comment: I saw that sneaky edit ;) Note: there's no benefit doing an `& 0xFF` if you know the source is `byte` - there are no other bits that can be set